# Estimate the number of real roots

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods, roots

Given the function $f(x)=a-bx+ce^{\gamma x}+dxe^{\gamma x}$ with $x \in [0,\infty)$,
where $a,b,c,d$ are real parameters,$\gamma$ is strictly positive and that $f(0)=-1$,

Is it possible to know the numbers of roots in an analytical way?

Taking the derivative and looking for stationary points it's quite a mess since it is required to solve a nonlinear equation. Many thanks.

Comment: I do not think that we can do better in general.

Comment: I've added an initial condition that may be useful. Since $f \rightarrow \infty$, thus the function switches sign, we can say that there is at least a root. But can we set an upper bound for the numbers of roots?

Comment: For $f(x)=f^\prime(x)=0$, so there would be a jump of two in the number of roots, it is easy to find $\gamma$ in terms of $(a,b,c,d,x)$.  Use that $\gamma$ to plot $f(x)$ for a specific $a,b,c,d$,   to find $x$ where $f(x)=0$

Comment: Again looking at $f(x)=f^\prime(x)=0$, together with $f(0)=-1$, you have three linear equations in $a,b,c,d$, which tends to give a line in $\mathbb R^4$.  You could plot that in 3-space $(b,c,d)$ by ignoring $a$ which is just $-1-c$.  Keep $\gamma$ fixed, change $x$.  The line will move, mapping out a surface that divides $(b,c,d)$ with $0$ solutions from $(b,c,d)$ with $2$ solutions

Comment: What about using the fact that $e^{\gamma x}>1+\gamma x $, thus we get a a second degree polynomial with 2 solutions? Is this a legit proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial answer:

Estimating the values of the roots is difficult but the number of roots appears to be simpler or is it ? (see last discussed point...)

Indeed when $f(x)=0\iff e^{\gamma x}=\dfrac{bx-a}{c+dx}$

Since rational fractions of degree $1$ are monotonic as well as the exponential, there cannot be so much crossing points.

In fact there seem to always be $2$ intersections except when the horizontal asymptote of the hyperbola is in the lower half plane (i.e. $y<0$) where there is generally only $1$ but sometimes there are still $2$ (like in this case $a=-8,b=2,c=7,d=-\frac12,\gamma=0.3$), or none at all (with $a=b=c=d=-\frac 12,\gamma=1$), so establishing a solid criteria may not be so simple after all.

You can play with this Desmos graphing https://www.desmos.com/calculator/9ieqdmlyfx

Anyhow, I think this is a step towards a solution and conjecture there are $n=0,1$ or $2$ solutions.

Comment: Yes! That's what I'm looking for. Graphically I've obtained lots of result with n=2, but prove that there are at most 2 roots is gonna be a hard task!